# Visual basic replace a leter with another in Text1.text and Text2.text

Tags: vb6

I have `text1.text`, `text2.text` and `Command1_Click`
in first text i have :

WUJ QAZ SFX BG3 YBN HM OTDP WL DG5PY AGEW

without space,

i want to substitute this on click on text2.text with:

WUJ - 0

QAZ - 1

SFX - 2

BG3 - 6

YBN - 7

HM - 8

OTDP - B

WL - D

DG5PY - E

AGEW - F

result text2.text on click:
012678BDEF

PLEASE IN VISUAL BASIC 6.0

Comment: if this is VB6 why the VB.NET tag? If it is .NET, whats the `vb 6.0` mean?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one  way...

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim str As String
    str = Text1.Text
    str = Replace(str, "WUJ", "0")
    str = Replace(str, "QAZ", "1")
    str = Replace(str, "SFX", "2")
    str = Replace(str, "BG3", "6")
    str = Replace(str, "YBN", "7")
    str = Replace(str, "HM", "8")
    str = Replace(str, "OTDP", "B")
    str = Replace(str, "WL", "D")
    str = Replace(str, "DG5PY", "E")
    str = Replace(str, "AGEW", "F")
    Text2.Text = str
End Sub
```

Comment: dont work on entire code:WUJQAZSFXBG3YBNHMOTDPWLDG5PYAGEW = 012678BDEF

Comment: Gotcha...just get rid of all the spaces (I'll edit the code).  Be aware, though, that if any of the sequences to be replaced have **letters in common**, then this could result in the wrong output.  It all depends on the order of the replacements done.